# Enable OpenCL on Ubuntu 20.04 for Darktable on Thinkpad T495(AMD iGPU)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, thinkpad, amdgpu, darktable

I have a Thinkpad T495 with AMD 3500 PRO:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev d2)
```

Using clinfo command I can see that the platform has an OpenCL profile:

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3182.0)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform
```

I tried install amdgpu-pro, but the installation failed with this error

```
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.6.0.15-1098277_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/amdgpu-dkms-firmware/LICENSE', which is also in package rock-dkms-firmware 1:3.7-20
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.6.0.15-1098277_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Still when I open Darktable, OpenCL option is not supported:
[image: Darktable screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old query...but do you have the snap installed?  If so remove it and install the official PPA.
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=graphics:darktable&package=darktable
Thanks